# Laravel and Glide renaming an image

Tags: php, image, laravel, image-uploading, thephpleague

I've implemented Laravel Clyde https://github.com/antennaio/laravel-clyde which is an wrapper for Glide https://github.com/thephpleague/glide

This set-up works for uploading, caching and retrieving images etc.  However I need to be able to rename an image when it's downloaded.

I cannot see a way of doing this using these packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the purposes of clyde is to abstract those manipulation configurations. If you just use glide then the image filename will look nice but the user sees those messy params.  One solution might be to serve the file without clyde on a view that shows the full picture.